# Hammer.js with plain javascript

Tags: javascript, hammer.js

How to use hammer JS events without JQuery selectors just using plain Javascript methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a quick look over the GitHub documentation:

```
var hammer = new Hammer(document.getElementById("container"));
```

creates a 'hammer' without jQuery. After that you can set callback functions, you don't need any jQuery for that too. But beware! HammerJS might need jQuery internally, so it is possible you can't leave out the `<script src="path/to/jquery.js"></script>`

Comment: Are you sure about that? I'm trying to avoid JQuery

Comment: I am not sure about if HammerJS needs jQuery internally, but why would that matter? If you don't want to use it in _your_ code, you don't need to, you can use vanilla JS selectors to create a Hammer too. But if you want to test that, try _not_ importing jQuery, while you _are_ importing HammerJS. If it breaks and the console says something like `$ is undefined` or `jQuery is undefined` you know HammerJS needs jQuery. @Jacob

Answer (score 3):

> Bind hammer to a container element:

```
var hammer = new Hammer(document.getElementById("container"));
```

> Now, on every gesture that is performed on the container element,
>   you'll receive a callback object with information on the gesture.

Some example functions:

```
hammer.ondragstart = function(ev) { };
hammer.ondrag = function(ev) { };
hammer.ondragend = function(ev) { };
hammer.onswipe = function(ev) { };
```

hammer.js is available as completely standalone version, so you don't need to import jquery resources. See: http://eightmedia.github.com/hammer.js/

Full documentation: https://github.com/eightmedia/hammer.js#documentation

Comment: I have two container of image . can if possible to load container .

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: just use the plain old DOM API. You're not *obliged*, or *forced* to use nothing but jQuery once you've included it.

```
var someElements = document.querySelectorAll('.someClass');//not jQuery, perfectly valid
var byId = document.getElementById('someId');
var sameScript = $('#anotherId');//nothing stops me from doing this... using jQ for some things
```

If you find the DOM API a bit clunky (which it is), you might as well do something like this:

```
var pureDOMRef = $('someID')[0];//returns "normal" Element object, removes jQ wrapper
var multiple = Array.prototype.slice.apply($('.classSelector'),[0]);//returns Array
```

Just play around, switch back and forth if you want to, nothing wrong with that

Answer (score 0):

The new version of hammer.js provides a JQuery plugin which has to be understand first that it's not a plugin from JQuery - it is FOR JQuery. So if you use JQuery for your site for other purposes then it's convenient that you can basically 'apply' a plugin from hammer at a JQuery selector like this:

```
$(element).hammer(options).bind("pan", myPanHandler);
```

Since hammer.js has a modern OOP pattern it can use instances for multiple data handling at once, hence every JQuery element that is bound to hammer is an instance. (IMHO) JQuery slows down by some ms, if you don't mind use this plugin or stay with Vanilla.

http://hammerjs.github.io/jquery-plugin/